# Can it be acceptable to construct SQL queries dynamically?

Tags: c#, sql, mysql

I know that as a general rule, you shouldn't construct SQL queries dynamically because of the possibility of SQL injection.

However, it could come in quite handy to break this rule and define for example my SELECT statements like so and use it for all my tables:

```csharp
public static string SelectAll<T>() => $"SELECT * FROM {typeof(T)?.Name}s";
```

In this case, there is guaranteed to be no user input. Also, we're not talking about a public library or similar, but a closed app.

Would it therefore be acceptable to write code like the above or should one always act according to the rule that "you never know who or what will end up using this code and how" and under no circumstance construct SQL queries dynamically?

Comment: The specific example in your question is harmless. The trouble is (and @DocBrown points this out), people without sufficient experience tend to generalize in the wrong areas. A junior dev might look at that line of code and make the jump to `"SELECT * from X where A = " + unsanitizedUserInput` is ok (and it is *very, very, very* not OK).

Comment: You're just reinventing the idea of an ORM. Why not use one of the many existing ORMs that have already been built, tested, security validated?

Comment: There are a lot of things to take into account, as shown in Erland Sommarskog's article [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) - although that is about T-SQL, I expect many aspects will be applicable to other SQL flavours.

Comment: I don't know C#, but it seems like you still forgot to escape `typeof(T)?.Name` (with the rules for sql identifiers, not the rules for sql literals)

Comment: Depending on how important grammar is to you, I hope you don't plan on having a "City" class... (In clear: beware of plurals)

Comment: @Alexander Sometimes companies specifically ask to not use ORMs for this or that reason (Often not a good reason). I've had to build a handcrafted data-access layer by hand, without using any sort of ORM a good couple times already. Yes, it was completely miserable, but it was a client's demand. They "didn't believe in the security" of ready-made ORM frameworks.

Comment: @T.Sar the problem with ORMs is that too many developers use them to avoid having *learn* SQL instead of avoiding having to *write* SQL. I am deeply skeptical of people who say "lets use an ORM" unless I *know* that they know what they're doing (not suggesting you don't, since your anecdote illustrates that you in fact do).

Comment: @JaredSmith Agreed. Unfortunately, often ORMs are sold by using just that as a major appeal ("If we use this framework, we won't need a database expert!/to learn SQL!'). ORMs have their place, but the place _isn't_ the same place you go when you need to cut corners. They're power tools, and as any power tool, they can wreck havoc in the wrong hands.

Comment: @T.Sar The irony is that you then need an expert in the ORM and potentially its own SQL-like query language.  Then there's also all the wasted hours (really: days or weeks) trying to get them to do what you want in a reasonably performant way.  That's my experience, at least.

Comment: @JimmyJames Exactly. Which makes an ORM a framework-like a complex feature on itself, not something you can duct-tape to the project and call it a day. Sure, for smaller projects you can just spin some EF and call it a day, but you can't do the same with jumbo-sized projects without a care in the world.

Comment: Re. Naming of Tables and Dynamic Queries: Not something I would recommend, but I've seen a database with a naming scheme that looked somewhat like [TypeName]Storage. So it was CityStorage, UserStorage, ProductStorage, and so on. It looked _weird_, but it was gramatically not awful.

Comment: @T.Sar Agreed.  It seems to me that an ORM really works well when the DB was designed around it.  Of course, it's possible that someone could come up with a killer ORM and prove me wrong.  I've been using SQLAlchemy in Python for queries and I'm impressed enough that I'm almost tempted to try out their ORM approach.

Comment: @JimmyJames If you're having trouble getting an ORM behave, don't use it. But that doesn't mean you should concatenate strings of SQL yourself, there's a middle way: use a **QueryBuilder** library that lets you generate valid SQL from an abstract syntax tree.

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but most people use singular nouns for their table names.  So City, Country and Person; not Cities, Countries and People.

Comment: @Alexander The context here is Dapper, which still needs handcrafted SQL queries.

Comment: Re. naming: this method could/would have an overload with an argument that specifies the table name. I limited the example to the above to keep it simple (and if there are objections to the given example, the overloaded method is of course even "less safe").

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't advocating for concatenating SQL.  I apologize if that was implied.  It's probably worth noting that using an ORM doesn't protect you from injection either.  ["Hibernate does not grant immunity to SQL Injection, one can misuse the api as they please"](https://owasp.org/www-community/Hibernate)

Comment: Note that you should still apply the db's specific name quoting function to that.

Comment: Dapper is not an ORM, it's a facade over ADO.NET that's so thin that it might as well not exist, but people still use it in 2022 because they're either stuck in 2012 when Entity Framework was slow and bloated, or they've been told EF is slow and bloated but never used it, or they wrongly believe that saving a few milliseconds by writing hand-crafted SQL to do simple operations works out cheaper than writing far simpler ORM code.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

On one hand, I don't like such braindead rules, since they are clearly an oversimplification. A better wording would be IMHO

**You shouldn't construct SQL queries dynamically using unsanitized input data from some source you don't trust to be or stay reliable.**

On the other hand, such code bears a certain risk of becoming a bad example for junior developers in your team which don't treat it so carefully as you. Hence if you see a slight chance that this code will become an example for other code which could turn into a security risk, it is probably better to invest the extra effort for creating a parametrized query (when possible).

Comment: You might want to add a comment around the query that doing so can be perilous, should be done with caution, maybe with some explanation or a link...

Comment: Not all DBMS support parameter for table name.

Comment: I misread this answer the first time and now I really want a Code Bear plush.

Comment: @user1532080: yes, you are right, there are certain requirements which one cannot easily solve generically without dynamic SQL. Maybe I should have added a few words on this (but it is hard without making the answer much longer).

Comment: @T.Sar: as a non-native english speaker I hope my wording wasn't too unusual?

Comment: @DocBrown Your wording is fine! I'm a non-native english speaker myself, thus my confusion. I often go for the more concrete (bear => The animal) meaning first, which often makes me re-read text several times before going "Oooh, WAIT". Don't worry!

Comment: @DocBrown Your answer is correct as far as I'm concerned. It's just in the case you would still do it (either because you technically have no other choice, or for another reason), it'd be advisable to comment.

Comment: @DocBrown as a native speaker, I think "such code always bears" is a little more natural than "such code bears always", and makes it less likely for misinterpretation.

Comment: @DavidPement: thanks a lot, edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is I think the right answer.  In addition, I've worked on a system that had an extensive SQL generation component.  It was really challenging to reason about what SQL would be generated for a given state, let alone what it would do.  It scared me straight on trying to build queries dynamically.  If I need something along those lines, I stick to a *good* templating engine.  Not failsafe but generally easier to understand.

Comment: There were a lot of great answers, but I really liked the slippery slope argument here, an aspect I hadn't thought of, but is of course very relevant.

Comment: "Unsanitized" isn't quite right, because that's isn't precisely what parameterized queries do. That is, parameterized queries don't escape the input data to make it safe. Rather, they keep the input data separate from query data completely. "Unisolated" or "unquarantined" is probably a better way to phrase it.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: I spoke of unsanitized data especially in the context of dynamic queries, not parametrized queries. When you need to create a dynamic query and cannot use a parametrized one, you have to sanitize the data, not to "isolate" it.

Comment: Another example is `field IN (...)` clauses.  AFAIK most DBs will allow parametrization of individual values there e.g. `IN (?, ?)` but if you the number of values is variable, you may be out of luck — fewer DBs support parametrization with an array.

Comment: I have another quibble with the wording "Unsanitized" — it implies it'd OK to write say `field = '{sanitized_value}'` IF sanitized_value was validated to be "safe" e.g. not contain `'` quotes.  Validation has its places, but as second app-dependent layer of defense; first the code must use _correct quoting_ capable of processing any string without SQL injection e.g. `field = {SqlStringLiteral(value, sql_dialect_info)}`.  Separate the tasks of "encode the intended SQL syntax tree" from "which queries we should allow".

Comment: @BeniCherniavsky-Paskin: my answer isn't intended to explain all the gory details of correct, incorrect, safe, and unsafe dynamic SQL. For this, we have Stackoverflow and Codereview.SE.

Comment: The reason the rule is there, is because it's a bad idea to trust developers (including yourself) that inputs are definitely sanitised 100% of the time and there's no way an attacker could possibly work around that. The only time it's really acceptable is if there's no option for paramaterisation (such as some dbs not allowing table params), at which point, you probably want to use a switch statement or explicit whitelist, rather than just interpolating. It's not "braindead", it's there to stop one of the easiest and most catastrophic attack vectors.

Answer (score 20):

There's a whole tonne load of things that can go wrong with dynamically constructed queries. Hence the rule.

- sql injection attacks
- non-performant queries
- non cached queries
- server specific settings, character set, time formats, version
- SQL brand, MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle etc
- edge cases, what about views?
- all your code now has to adhere to the classname + s = tablename. even `Person` and `Sheep`

Now, obviously if you use a ORM, say entity framework, it may well be using reflection to dynamically create sql queries. So its not like it's impossible to do. All of these problems can be solved and you can make it work.

So really the reason for the "Don't dynamically generate SQL" rules is not any of these problems, the reason is what I call the "Tip of the Iceberg" problem.

Lots of people think that doing this will save them work, when in reality dealing with all the problems and edge cases means that it is *more* work in the long run. You have made a thing which deals with the problem you can see, but as you progress you (or more likely your team) will encounter more and more of the iceberg.

Comment: Another unfortunate caveat is SQL non-portability.  You can't generally build SQL string in one portion of code and send it to a DB in another place.  In ideal world that _should_ be possible — SQL is a query language, literals are the bedrock of query languages, and ANSI SQL standardized things like identifier and string literal syntax decades ago.  Alas .  DBs have _incompatible_ extensions to literal syntax, and what's worse options like MySQL's `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` may be a _dynamic property of DB connection_ (`SET SESSION sql_mode`, with admin-controlled defaults to make it worse).

Comment: 100% i will add some extras

Comment: What is it about views that creates an edge case in this context?

Comment: I guess its more that you only have one target per type, presumably you have a table with the data but you might have a number of views of the data with different names

Answer (score 11):

It can be acceptable to concatenate SQL, but only under a very narrow and specific set of circumstances. Before reading this answer, you should read [Doc Brown's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/442909/118878) and [Ewan's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/442911/118878) answers for a good warning.

- Don't concatenate variables/parameters.

  - Use parameterized queries/prepared statements instead.
- You genuinely do not know what the SQL query is ahead of time.
- Provide an obvious means for using prepared statement.
- Pay very close attention to any SQL that is hard coded in a different programming language.

The only use cases where I've used dynamic queries has been for search forms. Since the query depends on which criteria the user chooses, it becomes impossible to know that query ahead of time. One way or another, you will need to build up your query by concatenating SQL. The criteria the user chooses can change the `WHERE` clause and determines which `JOIN`s you need to perform.

### But use prepared statements for user input!

And code-review the heck out of that code.

---

To focus on your specific example, the table name is parameterized. There isn't much benefit to this, and as Doc Brown warns, this could set a bad example for less-experienced developers. Ewan notes some additional disadvantages when it comes to query performance, which I don't think applies to the small code snippet in your question, but will apply if you concat a parameter.

Comment: This. I used concatenation in the past due to a variable filter: creating all possible variations of the filters would have been possible, but it certainly wouldn't have been clear nor maintainable. On the other hand, the query was _still_ parameterized. The only thing that was dynamic was the query shape, and all the portions to create that shape were hardcoded static strings.

Comment: @MatthieuM. seconded. I'm no SQL expert, but doing almost the same thing in my code - it's a batch insert with an unknown (but limited) batch size. So I'm just lazily generating the SQL every time a new batch size is encountered.

Comment: @jaskij, and to be fair, object-relational mappers do this behind the scenes, too. It's all SQL across the network, and the ORM builds SQL statements based on mappings and configuration. It's all dynamic, but it does not concat user input with SQL. It uses prepared statements.

Comment: Concatenating user input with SQL is how you get Little Bobby Tables. Or that guy who got many, many, speeding tickets because his vanity plates say `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

> or should one always act according to the rule that "you never know who or what will end up using this code and how"

This leads to paranoia. Like security.

You can go mad and protect everything from possible (but improbable) threats and spend an insane amount of resources on it... And yet, you won't be able (ever) to protect the code from human stupidity or ignorance.

Doesn't matter how much effort you put into this, it will take me a day to pervert or bypass it if I want. I can convince my PM that, against all claims, this time was necessary for us to meet the deadlines. It's "*temporary*" and we'll get *(cough)* rid of later *(cough)*.<sup>1</sup>

So no, appealing the *common sense* won't work.

> However, it could come in quite handy to break this rule and define for example my SELECT statements like so and use it for all my tables:

If you look for ways to ignore and bypass *best practices* you will find many. These are solutions that fall into the group I call *happy ideas*. Everyone has one and everyone can make them work. Sometimes are good, sometimes are ... well, let's just stop here.

But, **just because something is possible doesn't mean you have to do it**. As I said, it will take only a couple of minutes to copy `SelectAll`, make the template more complex and insecure and elaborate on my reasons. At some point, I could succeed at doing this and I will leave an open window to *doubtful but accepted practices*.

> Would it, therefore, be acceptable to write code like the above

It depends on whether you can afford the trade-offs, or in this case, the risks. Risks, like security, are measured and managed proportionally to the threat they represent. How probable they are, how often and for how long we are exposed to them, etc. So, you are asking the wrong audience.

If you take measures to mitigate the risks, then it's "acceptable". But don't lie to yourself. Like @Ewan suggested, things can shift quickly and lead you to unexpected situations if you are not cautious about measuring the risks.

If you don't have enough experience on this subject, I would suggest implementing a well-known solution that allows you to do it in the safest way possible and is future-proof.

---

<sup>1: You can't imagine how fast projects embrace the *normalization of deviance*. Add then the fact that code, as evolves, is prone to get worse, not to get better.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

*As this is being downvoted, please do kindly note that the question is "Can XYZ..." and I am answering "Yes, it can". Observe the fine difference to "Yes, you must always do it this way" and how the examples are specific enough to not be misconstrued as a general advise to always do it this way in random, every-day application code.*

> Can it be acceptable to construct (concatenate) SQL queries dynamically?

Yes, while any dynamic query generation needs to do appropriate escaping (of SQL identifiers and value literals), it can be perfectly acceptable in specific cases to concatenate SQL queries dynamically, and in some cases it can be *much* better than an alternative.

Some examples:

- If you wish to *implement* an ORM library, you by definition will most certainly be concatenating (generating) SQL statements all the time within the library itself.
- If you are *using* an ORM library, you may never see any SQL yourself (if all goes well) but under the hood the ORM library of your choice does the concatenation for you all the time.
- If you wish to implement some kind of report generator where the user has great flexibility to set up rules, filters, joins and so on, you may find that it may be much more useful to be able to provide SQL fragments (for trusted power users) instead of breaking the language into component parts and providing all of it through a complex GUI. In this case you absolutely do want to validate any user-provided SQL fragments.
- Saving the data of a single user form, querying a single or a handful of objects, and so on and so forth, may require no dynamic SQL. In this case you would, again, use no SQL (but an ORM instead), or use SQL queries which are static, and with bind variables to transport the dynamic inputs. But sometimes you may wish to generate larger or very complex SQL
  statements within your own "user" code (i.e. not in the ORM) based on
  some logic within your application. This may even end up with no
  actual dynamic SQL, but always the same result - but you might still
  wish to use code to generate this instead of having a huge, SQL
  string in your source, difficult to understand and maintain.

Obviously, as with everything we do as programmers, there are *always* benefits and drawbacks, and picking the right tool for the job at hand is something one learns with experience; and often it also depends a lot on context (for example, the choice of RDBMS might influence aspects of what you are doing or should not be doing). Something which is a strict rule in theory might be perfectly fine to be broken in practice.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your third item sounds like you actually want the user to provide sql fragments in the GUI? Also while yes, it is acceptable, you should emphasise that any dynamic query generation needs to do appropriate escaping (of sql identifiers and value literals).

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, I've added your recommendations into the answer.

Comment: This sounds a little like it misunderstands how query parameterization works. Parameterized queries do not escape or sanitize the parameter input data. Rather they keep that data separate from SQL command completely, so there's no chance at all of a malicious input somehow out-smarting the sanitization/escaping process.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that as a general rule, you shouldn't construct SQL queries
> dynamically because of the possibility of SQL injection.

This is wrong.

There is the possibility of SQL injection and other trouble if you dynamically build SQL *without knowing what you're doing*.

That is why several languages and frameworks include **Query Builders** that allow you to do so safely.

For your specific statement - can you guarantee that it will work for all possible values? Especially with the type abstraction the answer is clearly "no", because I can easily declare my own type and then call your class and now I'm selecting from a table that doesn't exist or, if I'm clever and your DB schema isn't, from a system table. With MySQL it would even be possible to select from a table in a different database.

Answer (score 1):

I would not step down to manually concatenating SQL strings for convenience. This adds a lot of potential for errors that compromise the security of your application. If I can avoid this, I use an alternative like parametrized queries or an ORM or query builder. Having to think about all these issues would outweigh any convenience I might get out of this.

But there are cases where you can't avoid concatenating SQL strings manually. And in those cases it is of course acceptable to do this, as long as you keep the security issues in mind and ensure that all user-supplied input is whitelisted and everything that can be is still in parameters.

If you're using an ORM, you should be able to do most kinds of dynamic queries without having to manipulate SQL. In your example in C# it would be pretty straightforward to implement your function in EF Core, without any need to concatenate strings. But even then there are a few things that the ORM won't be able to do. The main case where I've encountered this are queries that are very dynamic and that adapt the returned rows to the input. Especially if it's not a simple select, but something more complex.

If you don't use an ORM or query builder you might have to resort to concatenating strings much earlier, e.g. if you have a set of filters that can be toggled for a specific query. It's not that hard to do something like this safely if you know what you're doing, but it's really not fun and becomes tedious and annoying very quickly. And if this gets more complex, it's easy to screw it up. I'd strongly recommend to use some query builder or ORMs if you need dynamic queries, if you don't use them you end up reimplementing a basic version of them anyway after some time.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things where: you can do it, very many people do it, and very many successful apps rely on it, *but* it's quite difficult to do correctly, and if you do it yourself without having extensive experience it's very likely that you will make serious mistakes. So we say "don't do it". But of course there's more nuance to it than that. The way I would put it is:

If you need dynamically-generated queries, use a mature and well-tested ORM or query-builder framework.

If you want to learn, *study* a mature and well-tested ORM or query-builder framework.

If you're really interested in developing such things, or if you need a feature that you can't find anywhere, *contribute* to a mature and well-tested ORM or query-builder framework.

If you've been doing that for 5 years and you're convinced that there's a better way, go out and write your own. You may find out along the way that your approach isn't as good as you thought — but now you'll have the experience to recognize it, which you didn't have on day one.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, of course. Whilst you ought to be able to predict your constructs and possibly even use precompilation to include or exclude clauses with commenting based upon bitmaps in Jacquard style is it acceptable.

Not everything is acceptable just because it is possible (NodeJS, .htaccess etc.)

Controls are implied.  Knee jerk fresher "injection" objections are just noise. This is done in production commonly and has been done so for a very long time.

Given 2 "bucket" tables, would you write 2 effectively identical queries or parameterise the names? What about hashing across 10 of them?

Why do you think "WHERE 1" is widely used?

Even driven by user input, providing they only enter boolean (checkbox) or cleansed/validated  types (numbers, strings, dates) injection is foiled.